# Omitting first 5 lines Streamreader

Tags: vb.net, streamreader

I'm using this simple code to read a textfile and return the values to a text box

```
  Dim xread As StreamReader
  xread = File.OpenText(AllDetails(n).uPath & ".txt")
  Do Until xread.EndOfStream
      lstEmail.Text = lstEmail.Text & xread.ReadLine & vbCrLf
  Loop
```

At the top of my text file will always be 5 lines that start something like `name=`. I want to bypass the first 5 lines and only return what's after that.

Any pointers please?

Comment: How big is your file? How many lines are supposed to be present? More efficient choices are available if the file is not too big

Comment: After the first 5 lines, there would only be at the most 10 more entries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just do this but I'd suggest a better approach, see below.

```
Dim xread = File.OpenText(AllDetails(n).uPath & ".txt")

xread.ReadLine()
xread.ReadLine()
xread.ReadLine()
xread.ReadLine()
xread.ReadLine()

Do Until xread.EndOfStream
      lstEmail.Text = lstEmail.Text & xread.ReadLine() & vbCrLf
Loop
```

or better,

```
lstEmail.Text = String.Join( _
   vbCrlf, _
   File.ReadLines(AllDetails(n).uPath & ".txt").Skip(5))
```

since, as you state, the file is **always** "small"

```
lstEmail.Text = String.Join( _
   vbCrlf, _
   File.ReadAllLines(AllDetails(n).uPath & ".txt").Skip(5))
```

use `File.ReadAllLines`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to skip the first five lines, just read them five times but don't do anything with them

```
Dim xread As StreamReader
xread = File.OpenText(AllDetails(n).uPath & ".txt")
For a = 1 To 5
    xread.ReadLine()
Next
Do Until xread.EndOfStream
    lstEmail.Text = lstEmail.Text & xread.ReadLine & vbCrLf
Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Just count the number of lines you are reading and when over five then process it

```
    Dim xread As StreamReader
    Dim lineNo As Integer = 1
    xread = File.OpenText(AllDetails(n).uPath & ".txt")
    Do Until xread.EndOfStream
        If lineNo > 5 Then
            lstEmail.Text = lstEmail.Text & xread.ReadLine & vbCrLf
        Else
            lineNo += 1
        End If
    Loop
```